# How do I multithread this function? What's wrong with my current syntax?

Tags: python, multithreading, function

My current, single threaded call to my function looks like this:

```
deepdream(net, frame, end=layersloop[frame_i % len(layersloop)],iter_n = 5)
```

Which works just fine single-threaded.

But I want to make it multithreaded. Right now I have a code that looks like this:

```
if threading.activeCount()>10:
    frame = deepdream(net, frame, end=layersloop[frame_i % len(layersloop)],iter_n = 5)
else:
    t = threading.Thread(target=deepdream, args=(frame,end=layersloop[frame_i % len(layersloop)],iter_n = 5)))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Which basically makes it stay less than 10 threads. (So if the thread count is greater than 10, just do a single thread call. If it's less than 10 active threads, than do a single threaded call.

But for some reason, I get this error:

```
File "3_dreaming_time.py", line 142
t = threading.Thread(target=deepdream, args=(frame,end=layersloop[frame_i % len(layersloop)],iter_n = 5)))
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm new to python and don't understand what's wrong with my syntax. Help?

PS. I also want the variable `frame` equal to the return of the `deepdream` function. Just like it is in the singlethread.

Comment: I would say you have one closing ')' too many.

Comment: Tried removing one, still didn't work. I am sure I have just the right amount of closes before, though.

Comment: Marcin is right.  Also you have mixed keyword arguments in with the positional ones in arg=().  Keyword arguments must go into kwds={} in the Thread constructor.  I rarely downvote a question, but I did so here because you didn't put much thought into this.  It's not too much to ask you to count your parenthesis in a line where the compiler is telling you there is a syntax error.

Comment: t = threading.Thread(target=deepdream, args=(frame,kwds={end=layersloop[frame_i % len(layersloop)],iter_n = 5}))

Still invalid syntax.

Comment: I don't think it is very good style to give `end` a default value like this.  Why don't you define a global or wrap it inside of a decorator function so you don't need to generate it in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the keyword arguments to `threading.Thread()` for the target invocation incorrectly. Try this instead:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=deepdream, 
                     args=(frame,), 
                     kwargs=dict(end=layersloop[frame_i % len(layersloop)],
                                 iter_n=5))
```

Comment: Great! Now how would I go about making the variable of "frame" be the return of the "deepdream" function as called upon by the thread constructor.

Comment: What you say you want the `frame` variable to be set to makes no sense when the function is being executed simultaneously by multiple threads. In other words, when several `deepdream` invocations are running, which return value (if any) should it be set to?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the following tuple:

```
(frame,end=layersloop[frame_i % len(layersloop)],iter_n = 5)
```

You can't supply default values for a tuple. It is not a function so parameter defaults don't make sense here.

Try the following:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=deepdream, args=(frame,layersloop[frame_i % len(layersloop)],5)))
```

I guess the problem here is that when creating a `Thread` to run a function (`deepdream`), the syntax is quite different from just calling a function without `Thread`s. Your use case here should not be a problem however, just change your line to the one I gave.

Also make sure below you have:

```
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

This step will wait for the threads to complete before ending the program.

As for your `frame` variable, it is passed each time to `deepdream`. It may be overwritten on each execution of the `deepdream` function. We will have to see how it interacts with `frame` to fully understand.

Comment: Sorry if my answer was not clear. He is providing a functional default value as a member of a tuple. This syntax is only valid in a function definition or function call. It's not using a tuple as a default value that is the issue.